# Write sass base on bootstrap, how to output separate files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

for example, I write a sass:

```
@import "bootstrap.scss";

.my-btn {
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-primary;
}
```

and below buttons are same:

```html
<button class="my-btn">ok</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary">ok</button>
```

It works, but I get a large file, `.my-btn` and all bootstrap content

How I get two files, one file is bootstrap.css, other file is my change about `.my-btn` ?

Comment: What are you using? Gulp? Node? Show your config file.

Comment: @llobet I'm using `node-sass` , and it is a golang web project

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap-sass and import `bootstrap/buttons` to avoid unnecessary styles.

```
@import "bootstrap/buttons";    
.my-btn {
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-primary;
}
```